# Woocommerce - How to programmatically stop sending email notification (sometime)

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try not to send email notification on woocommerce, only in some cases. **Not all the time**.

For example, I do not want to send the email for a new order that will contain the product X.

I searched for a special hook, but I didn't find out...
I tried to put an "exit" on `email-header.php` but it's not the good solution.
Do you know if there is a hook to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this code to add in the `functions.php` file of your theme.
Replace `xxx` with the `ID` of the product

```
function change_email_recipient_depending_of_product_id( $recipient, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ( $product_id == xxx ) {
            $recipient = '';
        }
        return $recipient;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'change_email_recipient_depending_of_product_id', 10, 2 );
```